# Error in Drawing Graphics

Tags: c#

I have a bug with this code but it runs and I don't see where.

```
System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200);
graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
```

Comment: what's the bug? what did, or didn't happen, that you weren't expecting?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check line 2 of your code. You only having 3 dimensions instead of having four.

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 2 points (4 coordinates) to draw a rectangle, maybe you wanted to do

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, x);
```

where `x` is the fourth coordinate (which you have to add)?

Comment: Where is the fourth parameter?

Comment: he should add a number in place of x in the code (I edited the answer, thanks)

Comment: Much appreciated for the guidance.